# Why setting a client-side timeout when using long polling?

Tags: javascript, comet, long-polling, instant-messaging, instant

In almost every long polling examples I see, there is something like a timeout of 30 seconds client-side. What is the precise reason for this?

Comment: @Mörre What is the problem? (English is not my native language.)

Comment: I have been asking myself the same thing and I could not find an answer. Everybody uses 30 secs without explaining why. Nice to find your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some routers, proxies or whatever device there is in the middle might decide to drop TCP/IP connections being idle for extensive period of time. Also refreshing connection once in a while makes sure you'll discover server failure quicker.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, XMLHttpRequest's readyState does not change when a TCP connection is dropped?

Comment: @Supercactus: it should if remote server/OS closes the connection. But if you simply cut off the network cable, you might not be notified.