# Long polling waiting timeout

Tags: jquery, ajax, long-polling

I'm implementing a very basic long-polling scenario in my web-app to get server notifications.
That's my client-side code

```
(function poll()
{
    $.ajax({ url: "server.php", success: function( data )
    {
        // data management

    }, dataType: "json", complete: poll, timeout: 15000 });    
})();
```

On the server side there is a simple while(true) loop that waits for a new message and then prints out the result.
It works; it's, however, not working as it should: the message sent from the server is received by the client whenever the timeout expires and the function **poll** is called again and not whenever the server fires up the notification (as it is supposed to be).

Any ideas why it's working as a "setInterval" and not as it should?
Thanks

Comment: *"the message sent from the server is received by the client whenever the timeout expires and the function poll is called again"* that's exactly how it's supposed to work. That's why long polling is inefficient compared to websockets. Long-polling requires sending a request to the server with a timeout. If no response happens within the timeout, the request ends and a new one is sent. you should limit your php to a similar timeout.

Comment: In that case what's the difference between this technique and a "normal" polling method? Something misleaded me, I thought it could work as a "socket recv()" or so

Comment: The difference is you're only sending a request every 15 seconds rather than every second, while still receiving notification of changes/new information near-instantly.

Comment: Let's say a 15 seconds timeout, if the server fires up a notification on the "first second" I have to wait 14 seconds again to get the message on the client-side and that's basically the same as firing up a 15 secs setInterval.
Am I wrong?

Comment: No, in that case the complete callback would happen in that first second, thus causing the poll to start immediately.

Comment: Got it, thank you.
The only alternative would be using websockets?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why setting a client-side timeout when using long polling?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14903223/why-setting-a-client-side-timeout-when-using-long-polling)